# not able to center a nav-bar

Tags: css, alignment, center, nav

I tried for way too long as i would like to confess.
I have a very basic site on which i after long trying was able to center the header-image, but the nav-bar doesn't want to.

Here is my css:

```
nav {
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #dedede;
border-radius: 4px;
box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
color: #888;
display: block;
margin: 8px 22px 8px 22px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 510px;
text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Here is my html:

```
<div style="text-align:center"><img src="/images/headerbackgr1.png" alt="header_backgr"></div>

<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/owncloud/index.php">ownCloud</a></li>
    <li><a href="download.php">Downloads</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="about.html">Über BenDroid <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <!--ausgeblendete Optionen
                <li><a href="location.htm">Standort</a></li>
                <li><a href="staff.htm">Team</a></li>
                -->
                <li><a href="contact.php">Kontakt</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

heres a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/68x4uL1g/1/

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Give your Nav element a margin that makes sense for this scenario:

```
margin: 8px auto;
```

This will automatically give the element a top and bottom margin of 8px and center it on the left and right margins making them equal.

You currently have

```
margin: 8px 22px 8px 22px;
```

Which specifies your left and right margins to be 22px which is having an unwanted affect on the menu.

Here is your fiddle with that change:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/68x4uL1g/2/)

**REMINDER:** This is correct, but remember that this will center the `nav` across the parent containing element. Keep that in mind when defining widths for containing elements.

Comment: Thank you. I feel pretty dumb now.

Comment: @BenDroid No question is a stupid question. Just make sure that you accept answers when you ask questions. Accepting helpful answers is just as important as asking good questions here on SO. It's what makes this site helpful to others that follow after us.